# jquery post and redirect onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, window.location

I have this html code

```
<div>
 <div><input id="wpsl-search-input1"/></div>
 <div><a id="wpsl-search-button1" href="#" target="_self">submit</a></div>
</div>
```

And this jquery

```
<script>
$('#wpsl-search-button1').click(function() {
   var url = '/pages/location-search/?';
   $('#wpsl-search-input1').each(function() {
       url += 'zip=' + $(this).val() + "&";
   });
   window.location.replace(url);
});
</script>
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. Any help ?

Comment: First, you're missing the `#` at the beginning of your input selector, and second, it looks like you expect to have more than one element with the same id, which is invalid html.

Comment: why are you using .each on a single input field ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me try to explain to you what you did and what you need to do to make your code work in the way you intended.

```
<script>
$('#wpsl-search-button1') // jQuery method to retrieve an element with the ID "wpsl-search-button1"
   .click(function() { // Attach a "click" listener to the element
       var url = '/pages/location-search/?'; // Declare a variable with the name "url" containing a string "/pages/location-search/?"
       $('#wpsl-search-input1') // retrieving the element with the id "wpsl-search-input1"
           .each(function() { // looping over all elements found by the id selector (ID's are unique, so the query above should always return one jQuery element. No need for a loop here)
               url += 'zip=' + $(this).val() + "&"; // append a "zip" parameter with the value of the found element (this is refering to the current element of the iteration -> the input)
           });
       window.location.replace(url); // replace the current resource with the one in the "url" variable
});
</script>
```

If you just want to redirect to a url based by the input value use this code:

```
<script>
$('#wpsl-search-button1').click(function() { // you dont need the .each, because you are selecting by id
   var inputURL = $('#wpsl-search-input1').val();
   window.location.href = `/pages/location-search/?zip=${inputURL}`; // Redirecting to the passed url (also working relative to the current URL)
   return false; // Cheap way to call the "event.preventDefault()" method
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank bro! but isn't working --- when I click on the link it doesn't call the function --- always redirect to # which is the link on <a href

Comment: Put the script tag under your html or use the document ready function

Comment: I'm using exactly your code, but not working so far ---

Comment: Did you wraped it in `$(function (){});`?

Comment: for sure some problem with my assets ---- the code is working at jsfiddle >> http://jsfiddle.net/qES7c/

Answer (score 0):

Try executing it after the DOM has loaded, like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#wpsl-search-button1').click(function() {
       var url = '/pages/location-search/?';
       $('wpsl-search-input1').each(function() {
           url += 'zip=' + $(this).val() + "&";
       });
       window.location.replace(url);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When selecting an element by id, you need a pound sign:

```
 $('#wpsl-search-input1')
```